# What happens to the potential energy of an electric circuit during a voltage drop?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential-energy, voltage

Is it accurate to say $$ W=\int{Fdx}=\int{EQdx}=\int{\frac{dV}{dx}Qdx}=QV$$
so voltage is like g*h it is a potential field and charge is like mass. We know that the energy flux(vector) is given by the Poynting Vector and the energy density(scalar field) is given by 
$$ u = \frac{1}{2}\! \left(\varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf{B}^2\right)$$ 
Would it be accurate to relate the electric field and magnetic field to the force on an electron using Lorrentz law? 
$$ \mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$$ to get the energy in terms of acceleration(vector) of an electron or can one only consider the energy in terms of electric and magnetic field and voltage? 
Simplifying to give $$ F=ma=EQ \implies E \cdot E=(\frac{m}{q})^2 |a|^2$$
Where m is the mass of an electron and q is its charge